# How to change the thickness of a sparkline?

Tags: diagrams, ubuntu

I tried to use a sparkline in my text, as shown in the [documentation](http://vesta.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/graphics/sparklines/sparklines.pdf):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{sparklines}

\begin{document}

\begin{sparkline}{5}
\sparkspike .083 .18
\sparkspike .25 .55
\sparkspike .417 1
\sparkspike .583 .62
\sparkspike .75 .42
\sparkspike .917 .5
\spark 0.1 0.95  0.2 0.8  0.3 0.3  0.4 0.52  0.5 0.62
0.6 0.7   0.7 0.5  0.8 0.4  0.9 0.25  1 0.2 /
\sparkdot 1 0.2 blue
\end{sparkline}\space

\end{document}
```

However, the line is too thick and blocks out the bars:

[image]

According to the documentation the thickness of the line can be changed using:

```
\setlength\sparklinethickness{0.2pt}
```

But this does not change the thickness of the line. I am using Kubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a wrong version of the sparklines package. The default version installed with (K)Ubuntu 16.04 is sparklines 1.6 (an old version from 2014) which behaves differently.

### How to notice this

Look at the `.log` file or the output tab of your editor of choice. There you will find a section that looks something like this:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sparklines/sparklines.sty
Package: sparklines 2014/10/19 v1.6 Sparklines (see more about sparklines at ww
w.EdwardTufte.com)

Package: `sparklines' 1.6bp  2014/10/19
```

This tells you that you are using an old (2014) version of the sparklines package, while the documentation you reference is for version 1.7 (2016).

### How to fix this

The easiest way to fix this is to download the new version of sparklines (`sparklines.tex`, `sparklines.sty`) from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/sparklines) and place it in your project folder.

```
my_project/
├── example.tex
├── sparklines.sty
└── sparklines.tex
```

If you try to compile now, the local files will be used and you can use version 1.7 which behaves like you expect:

[image]

Comment: The TeX live distributions that come in the package repositories with some well-known Linux distributions are very stable (read: outdated). If you want to have a more up-to-date system with full control via `tlmgr` you should look into installing a ["vanilla" TeX live](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864). The strategy of updating only some packages directly from CTAN may work in some cases, but can cause more problems with more complex packages with many dependencies.